# Match & includes? method

Tags: ruby, string

My code is about a robot who has 3 posible answers (it depends on what you put in the message)

So, inside this posible answers, one depends if the input it's a question, and to prove it, i think it has to identify the "?" symbol on the string.

May i have to use the "match" method or includes?

This code it's gonna be include in a loop, that may answer in 3 possible ways.

Example:

```
puts "whats your meal today?"
answer = gets.chomp 
answer.includes? "?"

or 
answer.match('?')
```

Comment: Have you tried both? Does something unfortunate happen when you do `answer.match('?')`? I think you should realize pretty quickly that one of the two won't work for that particular string.

Comment: You should consult the documentation for the [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html) class, especially the [Methods for Querying](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#class-String-label-Methods+for+Querying).

Comment: Thanks for the both advices!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [String#end_with?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F)  I think that is what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) Instead

[String#chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) will only remove OS-specific newlines from a String, but neither String#chomp nor [String#end_with?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) will handle certain edge cases like multi-line matches or strings where you have whitespace characters at the end. Instead, use a regular expression with [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-match-3F). For example:

```rb
print "Enter a meal: "
answer = gets.chomp
answer.match? /\?\s*\z/m
```

The [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html) literal `/\?\s*\z/m` will return `true` value if the (possibly multi-line) String in your *answer* contains:

1. a literal question mark (which is why it's escaped)...
2. followed by zero or more whitespace characters...
3. anchored to the end-of-string with or without newline characters, e.g. `\n` or `\r\n`, although those will generally have been removed by #chomp already.

This will be more robust than your current solution, and will handle a wider variety of inputs while being more accurate at finding strings that end with a question mark without regard to trailing whitespace or line endings.